# Proper use of timers in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I wanted to program an interval-timer which you can use for training. So there have to be a stack widget were the user can input the times for the training- and the rest-rounds and the repetitions followed by a press on a start button which changes the page and starts the first round-countdown shown in a display.

So if the user enter 20 seconds for training, 10 seconds for rest and 3 repetitions the numbers
20 to 0, 10 to 0, 20 to 0, 10 to 0 and 20 to 0 
should be displayed one after another.

The problem I ran in:

I tried QTimer and a QThread with a 1 sec-sleep-function and a signal-slot to the gui, but in both options the gui froze.

Comment: What is your main objective? Why is it necessary to use threads? Maybe the method you use is the wrong one but unfortunately we don't know it since you don't indicate it. From what I see one of the errors is `while(mytimer->count >= 0){}`, you should not use loops that consume a lot of time (>= 10ms) in your case we do not know how long that loop blocks the GUI

Comment: To display the contdown of each round. It is necessary cause if you have a timer in the mainwindow it blocks everything.

Comment: I think this is just using QTimer, I don't see the need for threads

Comment: What do you mean by *training*?

Comment: This was my first attempt but that didn't work. With this setup a smaller testprogram did work. So I decided to use it that way.

Comment: By training i mean sit-ups or stuff.

Comment: That it works for a given case does not imply that it works for everything, in your "smaller testprogram" you have been lucky or that the error was so small that it was not visible. You have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so I recommend you rephrase your question that instead of asking about the underlying problem these questions for a solution that doesn't work that nobody guarantees will work.

Comment: hm. Maybe your right, but I don't know which other aproach I should use since the QTimer option didn't work either.

Comment: I would like to give you another approach but I don't understand your underlying problem. Take the time (>= 30min) to improve your question, write it better and explain it in detail. Read [ask]

Comment: Your question is now much better but it would be better if you explain in more detail, for example in the case that the user enters as times for the training in 5, rest-rounds in 3 and repetitions in 3 that should be shown in the GUI in detail.

Comment: There is a nice little [Qt Analog Clock Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-analogclock-example.html) which might be of help.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't help a lot because they use the time and not a timer.

Comment: I think I see what you're trying to do.  Make sure to not inherit QThread, but make a QObject with a QThread pointer in it, then use `movetoThread(thread_ptr);` to create a gui-independent thread out of that object.

Comment: You don't need any threads for it. You got one problem, with threads you've got two problems (and that grows with every thread). It's simple. Forget about QThread, and forget about sleep. I mean it: forget that these exist. Now think of how to approach the problem :)

Comment: @KubaOber Your comment sounds to me like my hint with [Qt Analog Clock Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-analogclock-example.html) was not that bad. @zero That sample uses `QTime` to get current wall clock time _and_ uses `QTimer` to force periodical updates. Isn't it similar to what you want to achieve?

Comment: It is similar. I guess  in the program i made so far the problem is not the class for the timer/counter but the counting loop, which freezes the gui, because it is in the gui class. But how can I put that into the timer/counter class?

Comment: In short, you determine when you want your code executed next, and then use QTimer (either single-shot or repeating depending on your design details) to get signal at that time. which does the thing you want done at that time, and returns immediately. If you need something (same or different thing) done at another time, you again use QTimer. Your code must never wait, it must only react to signals (such as QTimer timeout), do whatever and return as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The use of a `QTimer` will not block the main window. This is the purpose of timers.

Moreover, you don't need to use threads at all, you only have to start a timer with the desired interval (for example, a tick every 10ms) and connect the `timeout()` signal to a slot that will process your application behaviour.
In this slot, you just have to handle the countdown and the state change (working time to break time if the number of repetitions is not reached, break time to working time and the finished state).

I have created such an application and it worked well. Maybe I will later make it available on github. If I do it, I would made an edit to my answer to provide the link.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have designed the solution in a very complicated way. With no code it's impossible to tell you what went wrong. 
If I had to develop a solution for this, it'd be in the form of interconnecting blocks, which can be delay blocks or flow control blocks (child classes of the block parent).
Each block has a next one and a trigger function. A delay block also has a time. A flow control block may have different functionalities, like pointing to a previous block only for x repetitions. You can use a global QTimer when a new delay block is triggered to trigger the next block (connect the timeout signal of the timer to the trigger function of the next block, then start the timer with the current block's time).

For instance, if you wanted to do 3 times 30s exercise, 10s rest, you'd connect two delay blocks with a repeat block.